# Unknown server tag 'ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender'.

Tags: asp.net

I get this error when trying to use the latest ajaxToolKit NET4.

I've downloaded it, extracted it as described in the instructions and selected the dll  in the toolkit and its loaded ok.

The code I've added is for a simple calender off a textbox using the extension calender

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" >
</asp:TextBox>
<ajax:calendarextender  ID="ce1" runat="server" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" 
                 TargetControlID="txtStartDate" PopupPosition="Right" >
</ajax:calendarextender>
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you add a reference in project?

Comment: Yeah I have a reference in the project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you included the library as a Page directive on that page?

```
<%@ Register
    Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
    TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"%>
```

Also don't forget to add the script manager - though I don't think that would account for the error